# Full Calendar's body is not displayed on load

Tags: fullcalendar, angular7, fullcalendar-4

I am trying to display full-calendar module in ngx bootstrap tab teg but at the beginning I am getting only header after clicking header buttons it is displaying all calendar

I have tried to move assignment in ngOnInit but it didn't work

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import dayGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/daygrid";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-calendar-module',
  templateUrl: './calendar-module.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calendar-module.component.scss']
})
export class CalendarModuleComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  public calendarPlugins = [dayGridPlugin];
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){

  }
}
```

```
<full-calendar
  defaultView="dayGridMonth"
  [plugins]="calendarPlugins"
  [weekends]="false"
  [events]="[
    { title: 'event 1', start:'2019-08-19', end:'2019-08-30', color:'red' }
  ]"
></full-calendar>
```

[Link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGSBl.png)

Comment: any errors in the browser's Console?

Comment: nothing, it just opens header part of calendar

Comment: It looks like maybe you have some custom CSS? The next thing to try is to remove that and just use the standard fullCalendar CSS, and see if you still have the problem, or not

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using this component in ngx bootstrap tab teg

Comment: Sorry I have no idea what ngx or teg is. I know what bootstrap is. Nevertheless, my point still stands. If you have a visual issue you need to verify whether it's a problem with some custom CSS (whether it was you who wrote it or not)

Answer (score 1):

this worked

```
ngOnInit() {
       setTimeout(() => {
           this.calendarComponent.getApi().render();
       }, 300);
   }
```